# Unable to access Graph API when using Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, go, azure-ad-b2c

I have a test user ID as `test@gollahalliauth.onmicrosoft.com` (without global admin rights) and I am trying to access Graph API for Azure AD.

**Try 1 (Success)**

I used Azure AD [Graph Explorer](https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net), logged in with `test@gollahalliauth.onmicrosoft.com` and using the API `https://graph.windows.net/gollahalliauth.onmicrosoft.com/users/test@gollahalliauth.onmicrosoft.com` to get the contents. I was able to do this without any issue.

**Try 2 (Fail)**

I wrote a Go program with profile edit policy

```golang
import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
    "os"
)

const AuthDomainName string = "https://gollahalliauth.b2clogin.com/gollahalliauth.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0"
func main() {
    conf := &oauth2.Config{
        ClientID:     os.Getenv("clientID"),
        ClientSecret: os.Getenv("clientSecret"),
        RedirectURL:  "http://localhost:8080/callback",
        Scopes:       append([]string{"openid", "profile"}),
        Endpoint: oauth2.Endpoint{
            AuthURL:  AuthDomainName + "/authorize?p=b2c_1_gollahalli_edit",
            TokenURL: AuthDomainName + "/token?p=b2c_1_gollahalli_edit",
        },
    }

    // Generate random state
    b := make([]byte, 32)
    rand.Read(b)
    state := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(b)

    parms := oauth2.SetAuthURLParam("response_type", "id_token")

    url := conf.AuthCodeURL(state, parms)

    fmt.Println("AUth URL:",url)
}
```

This creates an auth URL to get the token. I used the `id_token` to access the graph API using `Authorization: Barer id_token` and I get an error as

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "Authentication_ExpiredToken",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en",
            "value": "Your access token has expired. Please renew it before submitting the request."
        }
    }
}
```

**Try 3 (Fail)**

I tried adding `User.Read` in `Azure AD B2C > Applications >
<application name> > Published scopes` and used the full scope URL and now I get an error as `Error: AADB2C90205: This application does not have sufficient permissions against this web resource to perform the operation.`

I am not sure what the problem is here. Any idea as to how to get over this?

Comment: did you try making user as global admin and check?

Comment: Yes I did, still the same issue

Comment: But I wonder how the first one succeeded

Comment: You are trying to access his own details and that will be allowed

Comment: Ya so that means it should be able to work with others too right? In someway at least

Comment: You are trying to access Graph API using B2C returned token. To gain access on Graph API, you must get access from **App Registrations** registered application but not from B2C Applicaiton. You should not use above approach to make a call to Graph API.

Comment: Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet

Comment: Then what is the use of edit profile policy?

Comment: May be you Assumed like Profile Edit policy can do Graph API operations but it is wrong. Profile Edit policy is for end users - Real customers who they want to update their profile details by them self. If you want to do Graph Operations for specific user/ set of users then you must follow Graph API documentation and complete your tasks (either integrating Graph API in your Application/ sending Postman calls). Refer above doc and start updating user details as described from there.

Comment: Ok thanks. Is there a way for users to update their own details? If you can answer that I'll mark it as answered

Comment: If you just need a way for users to update their own details, you can use edit policy. Needn't to call graph api.

Comment: Umm then where should I redirect it to?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows#create-a-profile-editing-user-flow

Answer (score 1):

The AAD B2C is a specialized instance of AAD. You may consider it as a AAD tenant with some B2C extensions. Note: this is a separate tenant from your organization's main AAD tenant in which you've already created the B2C directory/feature!

You can access the B2C records through the AAD Graph API, in 2 steps:

1. acquire an AAD Graph token by providing the ClientID and ClientSecret to the AAD endpoint (e.g. https://login.microsoftonline.com/yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com).
2. connect to the AAD Graph REST endpoint (e.g. https://graph.windows.net/yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6) with the desired method (GET/POST/PATCH/DELETE), passing it the token obtained in step 1 in the Authentication header of the request.

The best example is probably the user migration tool provided by MS. The AAD B2C configuration is covered [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-user-migration) and the sample code can be downloaded from the [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet) or directly from the [Github project](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-GraphAPI-DotNet).

You should take a look to the SendGraphPostRequest method and its friends in B2CGraphClient.cs. The code uses ADAL to get the AAD Graph token, but you can also obtain it directly with REST requests. A simplified version in C# (you'll have to translate it yourself to GO, and maybe replace ADAL if it's not available in GO):

```
            // NOTE: This client uses ADAL v2, not ADAL v4
            AuthenticationResult result = aadAuthContext.AcquireToken(Globals.aadGraphResourceId, aadCredential);
            HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
            string url = Globals.aadGraphEndpoint + tenant + api + "?" + Globals.aadGraphVersion;

            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
            request.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await http.SendAsync(request);

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string error = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                object formatted = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(error);
                throw new WebException("Error Calling the Graph API: \n" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(formatted, Formatting.Indented));
            }
```